# WP10: Ad Mediator causing exception at program launch, can't catch

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

So I've been working on an old app I made to make sure it's WP10 friendly, and while I was at it I switched to the Ad Mediator API from the old ad API. But I'm getting this problem where sometimes, maybe half the time, when I launch the app in the WP10 emulator, it causes a Null Pointer Exception in mscorlib.ni.dll. Only happens when the Ad Mediator code is implemented. Doesn't happen when running the app on the WP8 emulator. Also, I can't seem to catch it because I think the code is running on a worker thread, so the universal exception handler doesn't work. Here is the XAML for the Ad Mediator, don't think it really matters.

```
        <WindowsPhone81:AdMediatorControl Name="AdHome" Id="AdMediator-Id-11111" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.RowSpan="3" Height="50" Width="320"/>
```

Any suggestions?